# How can i use List<data> and pass it to another class

Tags: java, android, twitter, custom-adapter

i have created a custom adapter in TweetAdapter.java. I have written the code as

public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private List<Tweet> tweets;
private Context context;
public TweetAdapter(TweetListActivity ctx, List<Tweet> tweets) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
}

@Override
public Tweet getItem(int arg0) {
    return tweets.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent);
    }
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tweetTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);
    TextView tweetBody = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);
    final Tweet currentTweet = tweets.get(position);
    String a = currentTweet.getTitle();
    String b = currentTweet.getBody();
    tweetTitle.setText(a);
    tweetBody.setText(b);
    return v;
}
```

}

but getting error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:219)

Comment: I need money, lots and lots of money..!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on your problem and your question ?

Comment: This is not a solution service.  We are not going to write code for you, even if you have attempted to write the code yourself.  On the other hand, if you have a question about >>your<< code, we will attempt to answer it.  But you have to ask it first.

Comment: Wrong way to ask questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

implemented

import java.io.Serializable;

in Tweet.java

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `context` variable is null as it is never being set.

Try amending your constructor to:

```
public TweetAdapter(TweetListActivity ctx, List<Tweet> tweets) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets); 
    context=ctx;
}
```

Comment: i changed the code as per your saying
but is giving this error now

    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

at

 if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent);
    }

Comment: I answered your original question. The code error you added in your latest comment refers to code that is not in your original question (there is no addView command in the code above) and likely is unrelated. If you have a new question, open a new one and include the relevant code in that.

Answer (score -1):

Check if this link helps you:

https://github.com/codelearn-org/CodelearnTwitterApp/blob/master/src/org/codelearn/twitter/TweetAdapter.java

Here is the relelvant part :

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {

     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private List<Tweet> tweetsLocal;

     public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tweet> tweets){
         super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
         inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
         tweetsLocal = tweets;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
         View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
         TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);
         Tweet tweet = tweetsLocal.get(position);
         title.setText(tweet.getTitle());
         TextView body = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         body.setText(tweet.getBody());
         return row;
     }

}
```